# How to copy paste a google spreadsheet table into gmail using google script?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have a google spreadsheet with a pivot table, which i want to be emailed automatically based on certain criteria using my gmail. I am quite happy with the email script and the cinditions however I cannot find anywhere a script that can effectively replicate a "copy - paste" of the table into the email.

I would appreciate any help you could offer with this.

Thanks

Agi

I managed to get it to work using advice from this community. Thank you!

I am trying to get it to display values horizontally i.e. each line a new customer record. However, i get something different. I am attaching a file with what I get and the code. I would appreciate any advice. I am so sure that the solution is just there but after many hours I cannot get it :(  I am showing the code below and I am attaching a photo with the current and desired outcome.

Many thanks

Agi

```
function testMail(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var responses = ss.getSheetByName("Monitoreo de Pedidos");
 // var lastRow = responses.getLastRow();
 // var values = responses.getRange("A2"+(lastRow)+":R2"+(lastRow)).getValues();
   var values = responses.getRange("A3:R12").getValues(); 
  var headers = responses.getRange("A2:R2").getValues(); //The headers. A1 TO R1 does not contain relevant data
 var message = composeMessage (headers,values);
 var messageHTML = composeHtmlMsg(headers,values);
 Logger.log(messageHTML);
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(),'test html', message,{'htmlBody':messageHTML});
}



function composeMessage(headers,values){
  var message = 'Here are the data you submitted :\n'
  for (var j=0;j<5;++j){ //NUMBER OF ROWS
    for(var c=0;c<values[0].length;++c){ //NUMBER OF COLUMNS, in the future this will be dynamic
      message+='\n'+headers[0][c]+' : '+values[j][c]
    }
  }
  return message;
}


 function composeHtmlMsg(headers,values){
  var message = 'Here are the data you submitted :<br><br><table style="background-   color:yellow;border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5><th>Title</th>    <th>Customer Info</th><tr>'
  for (var j=0;j<5;++j){
    for(var c=0;c<values[0].length;++c){
    message+='<tr><td>'+headers[0][c]+'</td><td>'+values[j][c]+'</td></tr>'

    }
   }
   return message+'</table>';

 ![Desired outcome][1]}
```

Comment: What does your current code look like, and what specific issue are you having with it?

Comment: have you tried to get your ss as html and use that as html body ?

Comment: Great. I tried html as per you advice on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658409/how-to-format-email-from-spreadsheet-data-using-arrays. I was wondering if possible to display the table the other way round, with header on the top and values below.  I have tried to create a code to dynamically change the size of the table but I cannot get the format i want. Please forgive me, I am a newby.

Comment: Code is now attached. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the email body as html and insert the  in there. More work if you want to mimic formatting. Try if and write back if you get stuck.

Comment: Done Zig. Formatting not necessary. As per my previous comment, i can't  display the table the other way round, with header on the top and values below. I have tried to create a code to dynamically change the size of the table but I cannot get the layoyt i want :((

Comment: yes its possible, its just regular html. Search on how to make html tables (with <th> for example for your headers)

Comment: Thank you Zig. I tried but got really stuck. I have posted code and picture. Thank you!