# How to ensure Script sends an email containing an HTML table with full range of data?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a function that will allow me to send emails to a list of contacts via Google Sheets. The email will include a subject line and a table containing the data from my spreadsheet. The problem i am facing is that the HTML table is only sending the headers and 1 row of data. I can't find the error i have made.

The table will be ever increasing so i would like to email function to include all cells that have data in it. Is this possible?

I have adapted this Script/HTML code from [How to format email from spreadsheet data using arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658409/how-to-format-email-from-spreadsheet-data-using-arrays) but i am now stuck with how to amend it further for my needs.

```
function testMail(){
  var emails = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A1:B1
  var dataRange = emails.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var subject = "Current list of BGC 4 Acronyms";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var acronym = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var abbv = acronym.getRange("A5:A50").getValues();
  var explan = acronym.getRange("B5:B50").getValues();

  var message = composeMessage(abbv,explan);
  var messageHTML = composeHtmlMsg(abbv,explan);
  Logger.log(messageHTML);
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {'htmlBody':messageHTML});
}

function composeMessage(abbv,explan){
  var message = 'Here are the data you submitted :\n'
  for(var c=0;c<explan[0].length;++c){
    message+='\n'+abbv[0][c]+' : '+explan[0][c]
  }
  return message;
}

function composeHtmlMsg(abbv,explan){
  var message = '<br><br><table style="background-color:lightblue;border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5><th>Acronym</th><th>Explanation</th><tr>'
  for(var c=0;c<explan[0].length;++c){
    message+='<tr><td>'+abbv[0][c]+'</td><td>'+explan[0][c]+'</td></tr>'
  }
  return message+'</table>';
}
```

The expected result is an email sent to each address in the list with a subject line and full table of data. What i am actually getting is this

[image: Email received via script]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
for(var c=0;c<explan[0].length;++c){
    message+='\n'+abbv[0][c]+' : '+explan[0][c]
  }
```

To this:

I assume that abbv and explan are columns.

```
for(var c=0;c<explan.length;c++){
    message+='<br />' + abbv[c][0]+ ' : ' + explan[c][0];
  }
```

Try this:

```
function composeHtmlMsg(abbv,explan){
  var message = '<br><br><table style="background-color:lightblue;border-collapse:collapse;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5><th>Acronym</th><th>Explanation</th><tr>'
  for(var c=0;c<explan.length;c++){
    message+='<tr><td>'+abbv[c][0]+'</td><td>'+explan[c][0]+'</td></tr>'
  }
  return message+='</table>';
}
```

Based upon your spreadsheet sample I think this could work:

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var rg1=sh.getRange(5,1,sh.getLastRow()-4,1);
var rg2=sh.getRange(5,2,sh.getlastRow()-4,1);
var explan=rg1.getValues();
var abbv=rg2.getValues();
```

Comment: Thats great! Thanks @Cooper. Worked a perfectly. I there any way of getting it to only send the cells with data in and ignoring the empty ones? Because my table will continue to grow i'd like to be able to make sure the whole list is always sent.

Comment: Can you share an example of your sample sheet?  If you don't have anything below your data then you can use sheet.getDataRange();

Comment: Thank you, I can share an edited version here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/170ch7S40cOhuOIG1b5dGGFotVwng2OJHEgvuMS2Au7w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: do you know what i need to do to edit the HTML table when using get.DataRange()? I tried it and it sends the table looking a bit confused. I had 2 columns the same.